# The entropy of the universe in an irreversible cycle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

Suppose we have an ideal gas performing an irreversible cycle composed by:

1. an isothermal transformation at $T_{1}$;
2. an isobaric transformation at $P_{A}$;
3. an isothermal transformation at $T_{2}$;
4. an isobaric transformation at $P_{B}$.

with $\frac{T_{1}}{T_{2}}=\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{P_{B}}{P_{A}}=\frac{4}{5}$.

We want to calculate $\Delta S_{universe}$.

I know that it must be

$$
\Delta S_{universe}>0
$$
and that

$$
\Delta S_{system}=0
$$
because the system performs a cycle, thus

$$
\Delta S_{universe}=\Delta S_{ambient} + \Delta S_{system}=\Delta S_{ambient}
$$
In the isothermal transformations:

$$
Q^{1}_{ambient}=-Q^{1}_{system}=-nRT_{1}\ln\left(\frac{P_{B}}{P_{A}}\right)=nRT_{1}\ln\left(\frac{P_{A}}{P_{B}}\right)
$$
$$
Q^{3}_{ambient}=-Q^{3}_{system}=-nRT_{2}\ln\left(\frac{P_{A}}{P_{B}}\right)=nRT_{2}\ln\left(\frac{P_{B}}{P_{A}}\right)
$$
and thus:

$$
\Delta S^{1}_{ambient}=\frac{Q^{1}_{ambient}}{T_{1}}=nR\ln\left(\frac{P_{A}}{P_{B}}\right)
$$
$$
\Delta S^{3}_{ambient}=\frac{Q^{3}_{ambient}}{T_{2}}=nR\ln\left(\frac{P_{B}}{P_{A}}\right)
$$
but then

$$
\Delta S^{1}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{3}_{ambient}=0
$$

**Edit (according to the "on-hold" valutation, and according to the answers of user31748 and user139981)**

In the isobaric processes we have

$$
Q^{2}_{system}=\Delta U^{2}_{system} + W^{2}_{system}=nc_{V}\Delta T + P_{A}\Delta V=\frac{5}{8}nRT_{2}
$$

and

$$
Q^{4}_{system}=\Delta U^{4}_{system} + W^{4}_{system}=nc_{V}\Delta T + P_{B}\Delta V=-\frac{5}{8}nRT_{2}
$$

In order to calculate the entropy change of the ambient in $2$ and $4$ we assume that during $2$ the ambient is at $T_{1}$ and during $4$ it is at $T_{2}$, thus

$$
\Delta S^{2}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{4}_{ambient}=-\frac{Q^{2}_{system}}{T_{1}} - \frac{Q^{4}_{system}}{T_{2}}=-\frac{5}{24}nR
$$

Now two issues arise.

The first is whether or not the assumption of constant temperature of the ambient is justified, moreover how is it possible to consider the ambient being at $T_{1}$ during $1$ and $2$ and then suddenly change to $T_{2}$ during $3$ and $4$?

The second, assuming the validity of the previous hypotesis, regards the fact that:

$$
\Delta S_{universe}=\Delta S_{ambient} + \Delta S_{system}= \Delta S_{ambient}>0
$$

Indeed we have:

$$
\Delta S_{ambient}= \Delta S^{1}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{2}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{3}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{4}_{ambient}= \Delta S^{1}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{3}_{ambient} -\frac{5}{24}nR
$$
and thus it can not be

$$
\Delta S^{1}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{3}_{ambient}=0
$$
as stated above.

This means that the irreversibility of the cycle plays a crucial role in determining the entropy change of the ambient during $1$ and $3$. However during $1$ and $3$ the system (ideal gas) does not alter its internal energy, thus:

$$
Q^{i}_{system}=W^{i}_{system}
$$
Now during $1$ the system increases its pressure, thus, being at constant temperature, its volume decreases and $W^{1}_{system}<0$, this means that the system receaves heat. Clearly the opposite happens during $3$. With simple calculations we are back at

$$
\Delta S^{1}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{3}_{ambient}=0
$$
So where is the error?

**II edit (according to a comment due to user31748**

The fact that the cycle is irreversible does not prevent us from considering it to be quasistatic, moreover I think this is the only way one has to proceed in order to solve the problem without using non-equilibrium thermodynamic (as it is implicitely assumed in the exercise).

In the case of a gas performing a quasistatic irreversible isobaric process (without friction), the system evolves through different equilibrium states close one to another, thus the expression

$$
W=\int pdV=p\Delta V
$$
is valid with the understanding of $p$ being the actual pressure of the gas (the one we can calculate with the equation of state $pV=nRT$).

However in the case of a gas performing a non-quasistatic irreversible isobaric process (without friction), the system does not evolves through different equilibrium states, nevertheless the external pressure is constant (because the process is isobaric) and the expression

$$
W=\int p_{ext}dV=p_{ext}\Delta V
$$
is valid with the understanding of $p_{ext}$ being the external pressure.

This is why I think that my derivation of the value of the work in $2$ and $4$ is correct.

Obviously I do not want to sound arrogant, I know I could be completely wrong, and thus I hope will answer (moreover I think the question can no longer be seen as a mere homework because of the sublety of the reasoning involved and thus could be made "off-hold").

Comment: Why the cycle is irreversible? If the heat transfer takes place when the system and the environment is at the same temperature, then it is reversible.

Comment: this is an exercise I found and the irreversibility is an assumption

Comment: Why change in 2, 4 =0?

Comment: I can't see it. Can you put it in your post?

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on whether heat transfer takes place from a high temperature to a low temperature. So you should add details of the process. I suppose you assume the environment is at $T_1$ in 1 and $T_2$ in 3. Then these two processes are reversible. What about 2 and 4? What are the temperatures of the environment? If the environment is at a higher temperature than the system when heat flows into the system (or vice versa), then 2, 4 have $\Delta S >0$ and are irreversible.

OK. In the derivation you just added, you are assuming that the environment and the system are always at the same temperature throughout the whole process. Then of course the process has $\Delta S = 0$ and is reversible.

I guess the question assumes that the environment is kept at $T_1$ in process 2, and kept at $T_3$ in process 4. Then your derivation in 3 and 4 doesn't hold.

Comment: the fact is that the exercise starts saying: "consider an irreversible cycle..."

Comment: moreover in $2$ and $4$ the temperature of the system changes

Comment: According to your intuition of the constancy of the temperature of the environment during the isobaric processes (with which I agree), we have $$ \Delta S_{ambient}^{2}=-\frac{Q^{2}_{system}}{T_{1}}=-\frac{5}{6}nR$$ and $$ \Delta S_{ambient}^{2}=-\frac{Q^{4}_{system}}{T_{2}}=\frac{5}{8}nR$$ and thus $$ \Delta S_{ambient}^{2} + \Delta S^{4}_{ambient}=-\frac{5}{24}nR$$ Then it must be $$\Delta S^{1}_{ambient} + \Delta S^{3}_{ambient}>|\Delta S_{ambient}^{2} + \Delta S^{4}_{ambient}|$$, however I still can not understand how it is so

Answer (score 1):

It is true that $ \Delta S_{universe}>0 $ and that $ \Delta S_{system}=0 $ because the system performs a cycle, and also $
\Delta S_{universe}=\Delta S_{ambient} + \Delta S_{system}=\Delta S_{ambient} $
but it is not necessarily true that $\Delta S^{2}_{ambient}=-\Delta S^{2}_{system}$
This is because during the isobaric transformation the ambient environment is a $work$ source/sink and not $heat$ source, and during that segment the process is $adiabatic$ and $irreversible$. Similar is the case for legs 1 and 3, for example if the work is done on a viscous fluid isothermally, or on a solid by inelastic isothermal deformation. In either case the entropy increase is in the reservoir even if there is none in the body itself. See Zemansky-Dittman 8.7.

Comment: I am not sure that the isobaric processes are adiabatic. Indeed consider the first isobaric process, the gas starts at $T_{1}$ and arrives at $T_{2}$, this means that $$\Delta U=nc_{V}\Delta T=\frac{3}{2}nR\Delta T$$ Being the process isobaric (at $P_{A}$) the work is simply $$W=P_{A}\Delta V=nr\Delta T$$ where the equation of state of the ideal gas is used, then the first principle of thermodynamics says $$\Delta U=Q-W$$ and this equation, with $\Delta U$ and $W$ as above, is not satisfied if $Q=0$.

Comment: Your problem statement started with "Suppose we have an ideal gas performing an irreversible cycle composed by..." so the equation $W=P_A \Delta V$ does not hold.

Comment: why irreversibility implies that $W=P_{A}\Delta V$ does not hold?

Comment: This is a very important problem and concept and a simple comment line will not do justice to it but in an irreversible process the work done $W$ depends also on $other$ parameters than the ones describe the state of the system. In general, if the process is reversible then $\delta W = y_1dX_1 + y_2 dX_2+....$ where the $X_1, X_2, ..$ are the extensive state descriptors and $y_1, y_2, ..$ are the conjugate "pressure" or "force" variables. When the process is irreversible there are terms ignored, e.g., friction forces, and then $\delta W > y_1 dX_1 + y_2dX_2+...$